# Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC' in Cassandra Windows 10 installation

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to install Cassandra 3.11.6 in Windows 10. I have set the environment variables and my current java version is 1.8.0_241. When I run the command "cassandra -f" in command prompt I'm getting the below message.

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
   Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Unrecognized VM option 'UseParNewGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I get Cassandra to work ? Am I missing something ?